# Cookies of domain are sent to subdomain, how to fix?

Tags: http, cookies, subdomain

Firefox is sending my ".domain.tld" cookies when I go to sub.domain.tld.

How can I make sure that the browser only sends cookies of ".sub.domain.tld" and not ".domain.tld"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. If you set a cookie on `.domain.tld` it will be sent to `domain.tld` and all subdomains.

Although this may be unrelated to your problem, take a look at [sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net/) - where the Stack Overflow family of sites host their static resources.