# Kohana Framework - prevent subdomains from inhereiting parent doamin cookies

Tags: cookies, kohana, subdomain

We are developing a Kohana Framework-based website with multiple subdomains, using the subdomain prefix value as the key for content and configuration filters...

This works great until a user with an active session to one of the subdomains visits a parent domain... Then they get a combination of BOTH cookies from each domain, which can lead to undesireable effects (parent domain settings inherited by subdomains).

For instance, I go to https://test.ourdomain.com and get a cookie with a session ID in it. All further requests to this URL or folders/files under this host have that cookie sent with the request in the headers. When I then go to https://sub.test.ourdomain.com, BOTH the cookie generated for that URL, PLUS the cookie generated for the parent url (test.ourdomain.com) is propogated. These cookies contain identically keyed information with varying values, and sometimes the values for the parent override the one for the child, producing undesireable effects on the child.

Preferably using Kohana's cookie settings, what can I do to limit the cookie propogation from parent domains to children?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cookies of domain are sent to subdomain, how to fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789789/cookies-of-domain-are-sent-to-subdomain-how-to-fix)

Comment: Posting that as a duplicate, as this isn't a Kohana-problem, strictly speaking. it's a general cookie setting.

Comment: I do not see any answers in any existing questions regarding how to get Kohana to set cookies without the preceding period, therefore limiting it to the explicit domain set... To ask the quesetion another way: I'm NOT specifically setting my cookies to be anything in particular, so this must be the default. How do I override that default?

Answer (score 1):

You can set [cookie settings](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/cookies#cookie-settings) in your `bootstrap.php` file.

By the looks of the documentation, you should be able to append `Cookie::$domain = "test.ourdomain.com";` or `Cookie::$domain = "sub.test.ourdomain.com";` to the end of your `bootstrap.php` file.

This should apply globally where ever cookies are used (including native and cookie-based sessions). You might have to clear your current cookies when making this change before noticing its effects.

**Edit**: Just realized how old the question is, hopefully this can solve any future questions.